No longer pinged after comments were moved to chat, despite an explicit @reply
I have been participating in a discussion of an answer on the Physics Stack Exchange. Until now, I have been receiving pings to my inbox whenever a new comment was addressed to me with an @reply. Since my last comment (a question addressed to the answer's author), the comments were moved to chat. The author posted a reply addressed to me with an @reply (eleven hours ago, apparently one hour before the move), yet in this case, I have not been pinged. Is there something that can be done to ensure the delivery of pings in all cases?
This question seems to raise essentially the same problem, but as the cause in this case was apparently a now-fixed scheduler problem, there is nothing in the answer that I can apply to the current situation. I may be mistaken, but none of the questions listed in the automatically-generated 'similar questions' list seem to have an answer that I can apply here, either.

By "pinged", did you mean "the chat ping (pink/red circle on your display picture)", or "the notification inbox"? If it's the notification inbox, then chat pings only come to notification inbox after 15 minutes, although it can be quicken to 5 minutes from your chat user prefs.

@MetaAndrewT. It is the notification inbox ( I had not even noticed the other!) In this case, however, the notification inbox entry and dot had not appeared after 9 hours (and still have not), while the notification of your comment was here when I first looked at Stack Exchange this morning, 9 hours after you posted it (on the other hand, if there is a pink circle on my display picture from either reply, I do not know where to go to see it. Maybe my actions in viewing the replies has already cancelled it?)

The 15 minute delay leads me to wonder if the problem was caused by the comments being moved to chat less than 15 minutes after the reply to me was posted. The information I have about when the reply was posted and when the move took place is only precise to the hour.
